# Hosting Drupal and Django together on Production Server

Tags: django, drupal, shared-hosting

Is it possible to host a Django app side by side with a Drupal project side by side without editing the urls.py?

I have a full fledged website right now made using the Drupal framework,working perfectly.
Now I have implemented some stuff using Django and want to put it on the same server . How easy is this ?

Comment: I think yes. What kind of problem do you foresee? Can you tell us more about these apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty easy if you just want to host your Django site inside a sub-URL - for example http://mydomain.com/django/. Using mod_wsgi, for example, you'd just set `WSGIScriptAlias` to the directory name, and everything else will just work (you'll probably need to put that high up in your Apache conf so that it's picked up before the Drupal configuration).